# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: laravel, hosting

I am new to hosting site. My site is running, but  i couldn't load the images in phpmyadmin and can't do `php artisan migrate` it gives me error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I also have my `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=http://www.sample_website.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sample_db
DB_USERNAME=sample_username
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I avail hosting. so for `DB_HOST=` I use my domain name. Is there any wrong with my `.env`? I'm not sure guys. thank you in advance

Comment: If your database is in the same server you’re hosting from your should use localhost instead of your domain name, the external port likely isn’t open for security reasons

Comment: i did. but still the same.
also i forgot this error message:
at /var/www/html/kr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664

 Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution")


 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=http://www.sample_site.com;port=3306;dbname=dbname", "sample_user", "sample_password", [])

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the HTTP protocol.

Just put:

```
DB_HOST=www.sample_website.com
```

or

```
DB_HOST=sample_website.com
```